# Why is only one core used instead of 32 in my spark-submit command?

Tags: apache-spark, process, jobs, cpu-cores

I know that there are a lot of topic with this issue, I read a lot of them, try a lot of solution but nothing happens, my spark-submit job is still ONLY use one core on my 32 available cores.

With my spark-submit command, I launch a Pyspark script. This Pyspark script does a spark.sql command over a lot of parquet files (around 6000 files around 6M each, for a total of 600 millions database tuple).

I use an AWS instance with 32 CPU and 128 Go and a 2To EBS DD on which are stored my parquet files (it's not an hdfs file system)

I doesn't launch spark as a master, just using it in standalone solution on my single EC2 instance.

Everything works fine but the process takes 2h using only one core on my 32 cores so I expect to reduce the process time by using all available cores !
I launch my pyspark script like that:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 96G --executor-cores 24 ./my_pyspark.py input.txt output.txt
```

I tried to add master parameters with local like this:

```
spark-submit --master local[24] --driver-memory 96G ./my_pyspark.py input.txt output.txt
```

I tried to start my spark as a server and give the URL to the master parameter:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
spark-submit --master spark://10.0.1.20:7077 --driver-memory 96G --executor-cores 24 ./my_pyspark.py input.txt output.txt
```

But none of this solution works. Will looking at the process with htop I see that ONLY one core is used. What did I miss?

Comment: can you try submitting without specifying `executor-cores`? I think spark  uses all cores by default... also how did you initialise the spark session in your script?

Comment: @mck I read that it's useful to initialise parameters in spark-session because the java session is launched before the initialisation and parameters are still set. So I just do SparkSession.builder
                .master("local")
                .appName("myApp")
                .getOrCreate())

Comment: try `.master("local[24]")` instead?

Comment: oh my god, it seems to works ! All my core are at 100% ! Thanx a lot ! But I didn't understand why it didn't work with --master local[24] in the spark-submit command. Thanx for the tip !

Comment: I think it's overridden by the master=local in your Python script. I suspect local  uses 1 core by default, if you don't add a bracket after it to specify the number of cores. An alternative is to use `local[*]` to use all cores.

Comment: Great, my script finished in 10mn instead of 2 hours, thanx !

Answer (score 0):

You spark submit command is wrong.
You should'nt allocate 96G for the driver and you should specifie the number of executor and the number of core for each executor.

For exemple, you can try :

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 8G --num-executors 15 --executors-memory 7 --executor-cores 2 ./my_pyspark.py input.txt output.txt
```

And you should probably use yarn as a ressource manager. `--master yarn`

Also, define master("local") in the sparkContext, override your spark-submit command, you should remove it from your code.

Comment: Thanx, I will try it but I need at least 30 Go of memory to be able to save my result on a local file so I don't know if 8 Go may be sufficient...I'm a spark newbie so I must understand the parameters : you set 15 executors ? And 7 Go of memory for each executor ? So 105 Go ? How did you set 8 Go for driver-memory and executor-cores ?

Comment: each executors write his own data so we don't care about driver memory.